# Does Marking Objects As Serializable Incur Overhead?

Tags: c#, .net

If I add the `[Serializable]` attribute to a class, does this introduce any overhead?  How about if the class is never used in any serialization operations?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This doesn't add any overhead to the normal runtime use of the object.

Marking a class as `Serializable` doesn't even result in a size difference in metadata.  It just sets a bit in the typedef flag.  (Thanks to [thecoop](https://stackoverflow.com/users/79439/thecoop) for pointing that out)

Comment: It doesn't actually add overhead; `SerializableAttribute` is a special pseudo-attribute that sets the `Serializable` bit in the `TypeDef` flags. So it doesn't add any metadata overhead.

Comment: @thecoop, interesting had no idea abouth that.  Updated my answer.