# What would prevent a class from being serializable?

Tags: c#, serialization, xml-serialization

What would prevent a class from being serializable?

I understand that a class is not serializable by default because enabling serialization introduces overhead. But are there characteristics of certain classes that would prevent them from being serialized?

If it's relevant, I am specifically thinking about XML serialization.

Comment: Actually there is no overhead for marking a class as `Serializable` (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3731224/does-marking-objects-as-serializable-incur-overhead). For XML serialization there is even less overhead since you do not even need to use an attribute as `XMLSerializer` works on public properties. You may want to add attributes to control the serialization/deserialization process, but these too don't add execution overhead though they do take a small amount of metadata space.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are objects which can't be serialized. If the object contains handles to external resources then these often cannot be serialized in a meaningful way.

Examples:

- Open TCP connections.
- Transaction objects.
- Open file handles.

Comment: Also arrays of `ArrayList` or `List<T>`, `Type` as a property, anything marked `[Obsolete]`, enumerations using `ulong` values >=9223372036854775808...[etc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer)